# ¿Como agrego texto a un archivo existente en una linea especifica? C#

Tags: c#, archivo, filewriter, procesamiento-de-texto

Tengo un archivo de texto creado previamente "file.txt" ese archivo contiene lo siguiente:

```
#File
    
[ASSETS]
   
    
[VARIABLES]
```

Despues quiero agregar el texto -> "hola" debajo de [ASSETS], para que quede asi:

```
#File
        
    [ASSETS]
       hola
        
    [VARIABLES]
```

Como lo agrego a esa linea? tengo un bloque de codigo que se encarga de encontrar las lineas de codigo, pero no se como escribir en ese numero de linea, alguna idea.?

CODIGO QUE ENCUENTRA LAS LINEAS:

```
public int SearchLine(string pathFile, string Search)
        {
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(pathFile);

            int NumberLine = 0;
            int NumberSearch = 0;

            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                NumberLine++;

                if(line == Search)
                {
                    NumberSearch = NumberLine;
                }
            }

            return NumberSearch;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

creo que lo que necesitas no es el número de linea sino un reemplazo basado en una etiqueta, quizá este bloque de código te podría ayudar:

```
var lineas = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("e:\\file.txt");

        System.Collections.Generic.List<string> nuevoArchivo = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();

        foreach (var linea in lineas)
        {
            if (linea.Contains("[ASSETS]"))
            {
                nuevoArchivo.Add(linea);
                nuevoArchivo.Add("Hola");
            }
            else
            {
                nuevoArchivo.Add(linea);
            }
        }
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("e:\\file.txt", nuevoArchivo);
```

Básicamente es crear una lista de tipo string, luego se realiza un foreach por cada linea de tu archivo, en cada linea preguntas si contiene tu etiqueta, si es que la contiene, ademas de agregar la linea a tu lista de string agregas el texto o los textos que deseas agregar, en caso contrario, solo agregas la linea para conservar la integridad del archivo, por último se guarda el archivo.

Espero que te funcione. Saludos!